# How to specify timeout in d3 xhr send request

Tags: javascript, http, d3.js, xmlhttprequest, timeout

I want to set a timeout value so that if the server does not respond in that particular time frame then the UI should move ahead and not wait for response. I have used the below syntax so far but it does not restrict the UI to listen for the specified time.

```
      d3.xhr(my_url)
        .header('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
        .header('timeout', 2000)
        .send(this.my_method, my_xmlData, function(error, data) {
        }
```

I read [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#request_timeout) that d3 xhr supports timeout feature now. Could anyone please tell me how to use that correctly?

Comment: `timeout` will return the request instance. Also, it's not nice editing your post to make **another** question. As you can see, I answered your question. But now, since you changed it into a different one, people that look at my answer will find it misplaced...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Ok Mate will raise a new one.

Comment: thanks. As you can see, using `timeout` will make the request *"move ahead"*, as you asked... however, moving ahead in this case means passing `null` to the callback.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado its here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46924863/5346095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the time (in milliseconds) to `timeout` (in version 4.x):

```
.timeout(time)
```

Here is an example. I'll load a JSON file without `timeout`:

```js
var url = "https://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json";

d3.json(url)
  .get(callback);

function callback(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now the same code, using 1 millisecond in the timeout (a very little time):

```js
var url = "https://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json";

d3.json(url)
  .timeout(1)
  .get(callback);

function callback(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see 1 millisecond is too little time to get the file, and the callback will return `null`, as expected.

Comment: wow! It worked. But how do we specify the function to run in case of timeout?

Comment: Accepted the answer. But want to execute a callback on timeout as UI still hangs waiting for values. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46924863/5346095

Comment: Mmm, now I believe you have a **different** question! You want to execute a given function after the time limit, but **still keep waiting** for the request, is that correct?

Comment: Actually I want to pass UI the same values it receives in case I receive error from service. Basically null values so that It settles down. But in case of timeout the UI does not receives no values and my screen loader keeps running.

Comment: I am using promises so I want to reject the promise in case of timeout. so if I can get hold of this event in a callback then I can reject the promise as I do in error scenario.

Comment: Now I see. Edit the new question, adding this information, it will be useful to the other users.

Comment: any clue mate? I have explained the question in detail. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46924863/5346095

Comment: Adding timeout in 3.5.5 basically skips the request even when the timeout interval is 20000ms. Tried earlier with 200ms and thought it worked fine. But it does not. Any other way we can make it work in 3.5.5?